# how to store default username and password for login system test in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, authentication, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Trying to make a simple login system in Python using pyramid framework. What I want to be able to do now is for example if we're working in php we can easily open phpmyadmin and set a fields with username and password that we can use to test the login system.

**How can I do this in python pyramid project using sqlalchemy**

This is my model class where I created my table structure

```
from test2.models.meta import Base
from which model classes will inherit
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Unicode,     #<- will provide Unicode field
    UnicodeText, #<- will provide Unicode text field
    Text,
    )

class Users(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'users'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False,default='admin')
        password = Column(Text, nullable=False,default='password')


from pyramid.view import view_config
from test2.models.services.userservice import UserServices
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound, HTTPNotFound
from pyramid.security import remember,forget
```

This is the view config

```
@view_config(route_name='auth',match_param='action=in',renderer='string',request_method='POST')
@view_config(route_name='auth', match_param='action=out', renderer='string')
def dashboard(request):
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        if username:
            user=UserServices.by_name(username)
            if user and user.verify_password(request.POST.get('password')):
                return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'))
            else:
                headers=forget(request)
        else:
            #return HTTPNotFound
            headers=forget(request)
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'),headers=headers)
```

**What I want to achieve is a simple login system which tests the username and password then redirects**

Comment: For the love of all things holy, please do not store raw passwords in a database. **Even if** it's just a simple website. It's very easy to do the right thing store a salted hashed password. See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/python-tutorials/securely-hash-passwords-in-python/) simple guid for how to.

Comment: i will encrpyt that no worries and thanks but am worrying about how to implement at least one sample username and password for testing purpose

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of the official Pyramid tutorial, "SQLAlchemy + URL Dispatch Wiki Tutorial", which show both the wrong and right way for storing passwords:

- [Latest (v.1.6)](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html)
- [Master (unreleased)](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/tutorials/wiki2/index.html)

In the "latest" branch, you will find [how to set passwords in cleartext](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html). **This is absolutely the wrong way to store passwords.**

In the "master" branch, [we hash passwords](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/tutorials/wiki2/definingmodels.html).

Always hash passwords with a strong cryptographic algorithm that already exists, like `bcrypt`, and never attempt to write your own.   Also, to be pedantic, one "hashes" passwords and does not "encrypt" them. Hashing is a one-way only operation, whereas encrypting can be reversed (decrypting).